# Expanding an eigenvalue equation with a perturbation?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations, perturbation-theory

I'm struggling with my understanding of eigenvalue equations.

I am trying to prove that if λ is an eigenvalue of a diagonalizable matrix A with right and left eigenvectors x and y, then by perturbing the system such that λ + $\delta \lambda $ is an eigenvalue of A+$\delta \lambda $ one can obtain:

$$\delta \lambda = \frac{y^{H}\delta Ax}{y^{H}x}$$

where H is the Hermitian conjugate.

I'm struggling to see how a perturbed eigenvalue equation can be expanded to obtain the $\delta \lambda $.

So far I have that:

$$ (A + \delta A )(x + \delta x) = (\lambda + \delta \lambda )(x + \delta x) $$

and

$$ (A + \delta A )(y + \delta y) = (\lambda + \delta \lambda )(y + \delta y) $$

What throws me off is where do the $ \delta y $ and $\delta x$ terms disappear to in the result, and where the $ y^{H} $ term comes from and also the significance of the 'right' and 'left' eigenvectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick here is not to use $y$ since it complicates the derivation.
Expanding the perturbed equation, we get
$$
Ax + A\delta x + \delta A x +\delta A \delta x = \lambda x + \lambda \delta x
+ \delta \lambda x  + \delta \lambda \delta x
$$
Since $Ax = \lambda x$, we get
$$
 A\delta x + \delta A x \approx   \lambda \delta x
+ \delta \lambda x  
$$
where we have  neglected second order terms.
Pre-multiplying the above by $x^H$, we obtain
$$
x^H A\delta x + x^H\delta A x \approx   \lambda x^H \delta x
+ \delta \lambda x^H x  
$$

Since,  $x^H x= 1$ (we assume that $x$ is normalised), we reduce the above equation to
$$
 x^H A \delta x + x^H\delta A x \approx   \lambda x^H \delta x
+ \delta \lambda 
$$
Thus,
$$
\delta \lambda   \approx x^H (A -\lambda I)\delta  x + x^H \delta A x  .
$$ 
If $A$ is Hermitian, then the first term in the rhs vanishes.

By pre-multiplying, the second displayed equation by $y^H$, we also get
$$
y^H(A-\lambda I) \delta x  + y^H \delta A x \approx \delta \lambda y^H x
$$
which gives the requested result
$$
\delta \lambda = \frac{y^H\delta Ax}{y^Hx} 
$$ 
since $ y^H(A-\lambda I) = 0$.

Comment: Thanks. This assumption is removed.

Comment: The final result includes both $x$ and $y$.